# Summing values from duplicate keys in a CSV file without panda

Tags: python

I have a large dataset that looks like the following

```py
party,cp,qualifier,amount
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE_2,100
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE_2,200
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK_1,500
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK_1,-600
```

I would like to output :

```py
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE,300
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK,-100
```

Here is my python code so far:

```py
headers = ["valuation_date","party_group_name","type","party_name","cp_group_name","cp_name","qualifier","amount"]
data = {}
with open(t1file,'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = reader.next()
        for row in reader:
                party = row[headers.index('party')]
                cp = row[headers.index('cp')]
                qualifier = row[headers.index('qualifier')]
                amount = row[headers.index('amount')]
                if row[headers.index('type')] == "Equity":
                        new_qualifier = qualifier.split("_")[0]
                        if party in data.keys():
                                if cp in data.keys():
                                        if new_qualifier in data.keys():
                                                data[party][cp][new_qualifier] += float(amount)
                                        else:
                                                data[party][cp][qualifier][amount] = data[party][cp][new_qualifier][amount]
                                else:
                                        data[cp] = cp
                        else:
                             data[party] = party
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```py
  data[party][cp][qualifier][amount] = data[party][cp][new_qualifier][amount]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Very rusty with python apologize if it's glaringly obivous but any insights as to what i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: For code line `if row[headers.index('type')] == "Equity":` Where is `type` in your file?

Comment: Added now, I had to remove some headers that were not necessary for this exercise.

Comment: That doesn't help. You see you read the file and change `headers`. It should be in your csv file.

Comment: I get the same error message regardless of which headers I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pandas.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to drop duplicates of multiple columns and combine it with `pandas.groupby()` & `sum` to get the desired result

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>#read file using pandas.read_csv()
>>>df
  party   cp   qualifier  amount
0   ABC  DEF    GOOGLE_2     100
1   ABC  DEF    GOOGLE_2     200
2   GHI  JKL  FACEBOOK_1     500
3   GHI  JKL  FACEBOOK_1    -600

>>>df['Total'] = df.groupby(['party','cp','qualifier'])['amount'].transform('sum')
>>>print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['party','cp','qualifier'], keep='last'))

  party   cp   qualifier  amount  Total
1   ABC  DEF    GOOGLE_2     200    300
3   GHI  JKL  FACEBOOK_1    -600   -100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

map_dic = dict()
with open('test1.csv', 'r') as fr:
    csv_reader = DictReader(fr, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        key = '{}_{}_{}'.format(line['party'], line['cp'], line['qualifier'])
        if key not in map_dic.keys():
            map_dic[key] = {'party': line['party'], 'cp': line['cp'], 'qualifier': line['qualifier'], 'amount': int(line['amount'])}
        else:
            map_dic[key]['amount'] = map_dic[key]['amount'] + int(line['amount'])

with open('test2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['party', 'cp', 'qualifier', 'amount'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, data in map_dic.items():
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thanks ! that's the snippet that works best for me I think. Can I ask, how would you write to a file such that you only write the headers once and then the corresponding values ?

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
from collections import defaultdict

PARTY_IDX = 0
CP_IDX = 1
QUALIFIER_IDX = 2
AMOUNT_IDX = 3

data = defaultdict(int)

with open('del-me.csv') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if idx > 0:
            fields = line.split(',')
            party = fields[PARTY_IDX]
            cp = fields[CP_IDX]
            qualifier = fields[QUALIFIER_IDX]
            qualifier = qualifier[:qualifier.find('_')]
            key = ','.join([party, cp, qualifier])
            amount = int(fields[AMOUNT_IDX])
            data[key] += amount
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in data.items():
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(k, v))
```

del-me.csv

```
party,cp,qualifier,amount
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE_2,100
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE_2,200
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK_1,500
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK_1,-600
```

out.csv

```
ABC,DEF,GOOGLE,300
GHI,JKL,FACEBOOK,-100
```

Comment: Thanks ! I  am having issues with the following line 
amount = int(fields[AMOUNT]). -> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-106369.88. Tried solving it by rewriting as float(fields[AMOUNT]) but no succcess.

Comment: Please add the exact line that cause the issue. `float( '-106369.88')` should work

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify things, you might use just one key for the dict which is composed out of the identifying parts of a given line.

You might have to extract values by the header names like you already did. The following is based on the specified input. [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) is used to split the string once at the end in order to use the `party,cp,qualifier` combination as a key and extract the amount.

```
def sumUp():
    d = {}
    with open(t1file,'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'party' in line:
                continue  # skip header
            key, value = line.rsplit(',', 1)  # split once at the end
            d[key] = d[key] + int(value) if key in d else int(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already enough answers, but let me correct your own code to help you derive the answer and understand the original issue:

```
import csv as csv
headers = ["valuation_date","party_group_name","party_name","cp_group_name","cp_name","qualifier","amount"]

data = {}
with open('test_data.csv','rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
            party = row[headers.index('party')]
            cp = row[headers.index('cp')]
            qualifier = row[headers.index('qualifier')]
            amount = row[headers.index('amount')]
            if row[headers.index('type')] == "Equity":
                    new_qualifier = qualifier.split("_")[0]
                    if party in data.keys():
                            cp_ = data[party]
                            if cp in cp_.keys():
                                    qualifier_ = data[party][cp]
                                    if new_qualifier in qualifier_.keys():
                                            data[party][cp][new_qualifier] += float(amount)
                                    else:
                                            data[party][cp][qualifier][amount] = {}
                            else:
                                    data[cp] = {}
                    else:
                             data[party] = {}
                             data[party][cp] = {}
                             data[party][cp][qualifier.split("_")[0]] = float(amount)
print(data)
```

This gives you

```
{'ABC': {'DEF': {'GOOGLE': 300.0}}, 'GHI': {'JKL': {'FACEBOOK': -100.0}}}
```

The problem was how you were populating your dictionary and how you were accessing it.

Comment: Thanks ! Hmm that's strange though, I get a key error when trying to run the above code  `data[party][cp][new_qualifier][amount] = {}
KeyError: 'EWZ UP'`